# How to create self-containing (standalone) jar of each modules of a multi-module maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module maven project. The parent POM and individual module's pom are working fine (because code in each module runs fine without any dependency issue and `mvn:package` goal runs without any warning/error). Now, I needed to create a jar for each module.

Project structure with their dependencies is roughly like this

```
ProjectABC
|
|--ModuleA
|     |-Log4J
|     |-Guava
|     |-pom.xml  
|
|--ModuleB
|     |-ModuleA
|     |-Commons
|     |-pom.xml         
|
|
|--MoudleC
|     |-ModuleB
|  
|-pom.xml
```

I followed this
[Maven multi-module project - copying all "package" JARS from submodules into parent/target/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292752/maven-multi-module-project-copying-all-package-jars-from-submodules-into-par)

And, able to get all my sub-module's jar into a `mouduleJars` folder, but I cannot run any jars because none of module's dependencies gets copied in a `mouduleJars` folder. For example if `module A` is dependent on `Log4J` I don't get log4j.jar in my `mouduleJars` folder, neither log4J is packaged inside moduleA.jar

**Question**

How to create self containing (standalone module jars) in a multi-module project.
Or, how to get all the dependencies in a `lib` folder.

**Temporary workaround**

Right now, I use my IntelliJ IDEA ide to copy all dependencies (like log4J, Guvava etc) in a lib folder

and run maven generated `moduleA.jar` by adding the `lib` folder to the classpath. This runs fine, but I don't like this manual approach and wants maven to take care of it.

**For who think it is duplicate or already answered and downvoters**

My question is NOT asking 
[Maven Assembly Submodules Multimodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093520/maven-assembly-submodules-multimodules) 
Or this

[Maven : Multimodule projects and versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330093/maven-multimodule-projects-and-versioning)

I have already spent more than a day try to get this working with `maven-assembly-plugin` without any success.

Please let me know if need more details.

Comment: Do you want a ProjectABC.jar with all dependencies inside?

Comment: That should work too, if that is possible to do easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all the dependencies *in* the jars, you'll need to create an [uberjar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar).  Putting the dependencies in the jar is not the way jars normally work.  An uberjar lets you do that though.  [Shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) is a plugin that builds one in java.  You can also do it this way: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

If you want to create a lib folder, here's an answer that will explain how: [force Maven2 to copy dependencies into target/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97640/force-maven2-to-copy-dependencies-into-target-lib)

Comment: My aim is to execute code in ModuleB. As you can see from the diagram, ModuleB is dependent on ModuleA as well. Please feel free to suggest a better apporach

Comment: +1, both the answers link you provided looking promising. I will try these out and get back to you.

Comment: Copying all the dependencies to a lib folder worked for me. I have added  `<classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>` in all module's maven-jar-plugin. I wait till end of day for few more good information from others on it, then accept your answer. uberjar looks  great too, I will experiment with that later.

Answer (score 0):

I did this with the [AppAssembler](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-program.html) maven plugin. It auto copies all needed dependencies and creates shortcuts for your main classes. It's much easier then other plugins I tried.

For the uber-jar applications I use [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) for merging jars into one + proguard for shrinking, but AppAssembler is much quicker and stable to use.