# How To Change Package Name In DOT-CLASS file if We don't have .Java File For that related classes

Tags: java

I am having .class (Dot-Class File) file ,inside this file some  package name is available which I want to change but for these .class File I am not having related source code can anyone tell,How I will change the package name inside these dot class file ,is it possible or not

Comment: You know it's called just a "class file". You could decompile and recompile it, or straight up fiddle with the bytecode. Why do you need to change the package?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options

1. Decompile the class using tools like jad, edit the decompiled file
   and then recompile it. This is not easy as you might have to have
   all dependencies properly packaged to recompile
2. Edit .class file using a byte code editor like http://set.ee/jbe/ and 
   replace occurrences of package name. This may end up causing some
   unexpected behaviours if the class depends on variables with default scope  its original package.
3. Use ant task [jarJar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) ([some details](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2006/06/06/doing-package-name-kung-fu-with-jarjarlinks.html)) and then achieve the repackaging.

   **Disclaimer** : I have not tried these ever. I would rather leave
   `.class` files alone. And if you are facing a conflict, it is better
   to think of some [modularity solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=OSGi) or [maven modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325510/how-to-create-self-containing-standalone-jar-of-each-modules-of-a-multi-module) or
   maven shaded jars.