# How to build a Uber jar with dependencies from multiple modules

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jenkins, jar

I have set up a multiple modules project in IntelliJ. My modules structure looks like this:

```
Project (no pom.xml file)
|
|--moduleA
|    |
|
|--moduleB
|    |-Log4J
|    |-Jackson
|
|--moduleC
|    |-moduleA
|    |-moduleB
|    |-Log4J
|
|--moduleD
|    |-moduleC
|    |-moduleA
|    |-moduleB
|    |-Log4J
|
|--moduleE
|    |-moduleA
|    |-moduleB
|    |-moduleC
|    |-Log4J
```

`moduleC` depends on `moduleA` and `moduleB`, and `moduleD` depends on `moduleA`, `moduleB` and `moduleC`. The same goes for `moduleE`.

I want to create two Uber jars. One for `moduleD` and one for `moduleE`, each of them containing the module's dependencies, including module A, B and C.

I am using Maven 3 to manage my dependencies and the maven-shade-plugin to create the Uber jar.

I have added the necessary dependencies in the `pom.xml` files like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.modules</groupId>
  <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have added the `maven-shade-plugin` to the `pom.xml` files of each module. So far I am able to build an uber jar for `moduleA` and `moduleB`, but when I try `moduleC` I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.modules:moduleA:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.modules:moduleB:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

How can I resolve this?

If I build and run the modules trough IntelliJ everything works. Also I was able to build an uber jar by configuring an IntellJ artifact.

How can I configure Maven to do this? I need it because I want to use an uber jar for production and I am trying to setup Jenkins to build the solution after a commit.

I have red the following post: [How to create self-containing (standalone) jar of each modules of a multi-module maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325510/how-to-create-self-containing-standalone-jar-of-each-modules-of-a-multi-module) but I was not able to make it work.

---

**EDIT:**

This is the `maven-shade-plugin` settings in `moduleA` and `moduleB`

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

This is the `maven-shade-plugin` in `moduleC`:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

As you can see I am using the default configuration.

Comment: How did you define the maven-shade-plugin settings? without seeing what you set up it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets please see the EDIT section for the config.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html is there a reason you didn't define <includes> ?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do but my guess is that you want to create a dedicated module under `moduleD` and `moduleE` that will be responsible for creating the uberjar. So you'll have one module `moduleD-uber` under `moduleD` that has dependencies on `moduleA`, `moduleB`, `moduleC`.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I didn't define <includes>, because I want to include all dependencies. I probably have to define <excludes> for the Log4J dependency as it is used in multiple modules.

Comment: @Tunaki so I have to create a separate module (`moduleD-uber`) that will create my uber jar? Shouldn't I be able to crate an uber jar from `moduleD`. Creating a new module just for this seems redundant.

Comment: No, because it is of packaging `pom`, so it won't work. I think.

Comment: @Tunaki can you give me more info. It is the first time that I have heard something like this.

Comment: The question is, what exactly do you want to do? It's still unclear to me. `moduleD` is a parent `pom` project so it doesn't really make sense to make an uberjar of it.

Comment: `moduleD` is a console java application with a `main` method. The idea is that the application depends on other modules that I use as libraries, in order to reuse the code in multiple modules. I want to create a uber jar for `moduleD`, that contains all of `moduleD` dependencies including the module itself and use the uber jar for deployment.

Comment: How can `moduleD` be a Java application if it serves as a parent POM for `<modules>`?

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake. There are no parent poms. Each module have their own `pom.xml` file.

Comment: @IvanStoyanov, see logback-android's [pom-uber.xml](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/blob/d013e41/pom-uber.xml), which creates an uber jar of its submodule projects.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
<includes>
  <include>**</include>
</includes>
```

at the same place where you define your excludes.

The only occurences of `<filter>` I can find is in combination with the include and exclude filters.

Don't hold me on it, but that's my guess why your build fails.

Comment: It is still failing. My guess is that it can't find the .jar files of the other modules.

Comment: Have you tried making a seperate project, that includes all these projects, and that compiles it into an uberjar? To prevent http://mythologian.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Ouroboros-dragon-serpent-snake-symbol.jpg from happening somehow, that it keeps looping.

Comment: No I haven't. So far I have tried to create a uber jar for `moduleC` and it is failing. I haven't tried `moduleD` as I guess that if `muduleC` that is one of the dependencies of `moduleD` is failing, `moduleD` will fail as well. Are you suggesting that I should create a new module dependent only on `moduleD` and create a uber jar from it? How would this work?

Comment: See the new module as a complete package dependent on all other packages, it uses them and them compiles them all together into one well defined package.  
Usually in cases like these, I find it better to explicitly list what I need to be included a and excluded. Might seem tedious, but at least you're not suprised by unexpected things.